# Counter-example for $\tilde{H} (X/A) \cong H (X, A)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Yo! I was not able to find a counter-example to $$\tilde{H} (X/A) \cong H (X, A)$$.

It's a well known fact that for cofibrations $A \hookrightarrow X$ (or more generally whenever $A$ is a deformation retract of an open neighborhood (is this equivalent to being cofibration, by the way?)) the isomorphism holds.

The above isomorphism is equivalent to $$X \cup CA \cong X/A$$. So such space should be something so weird that the cone lying above $A$ does not retract to a point. I was thinking is something like a non-orientable surface embedded in a 3-dimensional space, like the Möbius band into $S^3$, however I was not able to make any considerable computation.

Another approach would be to see the complexes of abelian group directly. More precisely, let $f: C \rightarrow D$ be a map between two complexes. When $Cone (f)$ and $coker f$ are not quasi-isomorphic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $X=S^1$, $A=S^1\setminus\{*\}$ for some point $*$ should work I think. The quotient is non-Hausdorff of course.

Comment: @DanRust Thanks for your comment. Apparently this will work, but do you know some example preferably using (Hausdorff paracompact) manifolds?

Comment: @DanRust i think, this doesn't work. but if you take $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=\mathbb Q$, then $H_1(X,A)=\mathbb Z^{\mathbb Q}$ and $\widetilde H_1(X/A)=\mathbb Z^{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$

Comment: $A\hookrightarrow X$ being a neighborhood deformation retract is slightly weaker than being a cofibration, though they are equivalent if you restrict your attention to reasonable spaces.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas By resonable spaces,do you mean CW complexes?

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev Apparently Dan example works. The quotient will be two points with a weird topology, while $X \cup CA$ will be a circle.

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev Could you explain your example? The quotient $X/A$ have the trivial topology.

Comment: CW complexes will certainly work, @user40276, but it also works for a much larger class of spaces. However, I forgot the details. This is in May's book in the 'cofibration' section.

Comment: @user40276 sorry, Dan example actually works, we have $H_1(X/A)=0$. thank you, i thought conversely for a very long time

Comment: @iwriteonbananas I took a look on May. His condition is called neighborhood deformation retract pair which apparently is equivalent to having a neighborhood retracting to $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $A=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$. Then the quotient $X/A$ is homeomorphic to the Hawaiian earring which has uncountable $H_1$ (try to prove this). On the other hand, $H_1(X,A)$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z$, which is countable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First of all, do you know an example using paracompact manifolds. Secondly, just to clarify, by uncountable you mean that it's isomorphic to the product of countable many $\mathbb{Z}$'s while the other one  is isomorphic to the coproduct, right?

Comment: very nice example, but how to prove that $H_1(X/A)$ is uncountable? this is the most important (in my opinion) part of the general question

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev Pick one generator for each loop. Then notice that you actually can compose around all loops, so $(1, …, 1, ..)$ is inside your group, so it's actually the product and not the coproduct.

Comment: About my second point I was clearly wrong, since you can't compose the same loop infinitely many times. However you can define one loop that goes around infinitely many times without passing through the same circle infinitely many times.

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev There is an injection $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z\to H_1(X/A)$ which maps a sequence $(k_1,k_2,\cdots)$ to the loop in the Hawaiian earring which winds $k_n$ times around the $n$-th outermost circle. Intuitively, this defines a loop because the circles in the earring get smaller and smaller and we can walk all the circles in finite time.

Comment: @user40276 Sorry, I have no example using paracompact manifolds, and I would be surprised if there is one. :)

Comment: @iwriteonbananas I think it's possible to produce one example using 4-manifolds without CW-complex structure. I think I will ask it on mathoverflow.